# How do I get the box-shadows of my scrollbar to change on hover?

Tags: css, colors, hover, scrollbar

I have created a scrollbar with 6 inset box-shadows and want these to change colour when I hover on the scrollbar. At the moment, when I hover on it, there is no change. Here is the code I have so far in CSS for the scrollbar:

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 20px;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: mediumpurple;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 100px 15px indigo inset, 0px -10px 10px indigo inset, 0px 250px 20px darkmagenta inset, 0px -20px 10px darkmagenta inset, 0px 400px 30px mediumorchid inset, 3px 650px 10px violet inset;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 100px 15px transparent inset, 0px -10px 10px transparent inset, 0px 250px 20px transparent inset, 0px -20px 10px transparent inset, 0px 400px 30px transparent inset, 3px 650px 10px transparent inset, 0px 100px 15px violet inset, 0px - 10px 10px violet inset, 0px 250px 20px plum inset, 0px -20px 10px plum inset, 0px 400px 30px thistle inset, 3px 650px 10px lavender inset;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, everything here is looking fine, but you just missed a little point here. `0px - 10px 10px violet inset` this line will make your whole `box-shadow` property invalid because it has a disorder in the second element, so you just have to fix this like this:

```css
0px -10px 10px violet inset
```

Here is the full working code:

```css
body {
  height: 150vh;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 20px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: mediumpurple;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 100px 15px indigo inset, 0px -10px 10px indigo inset, 0px 250px 20px darkmagenta inset, 0px -20px 10px darkmagenta inset, 0px 400px 30px mediumorchid inset, 3px 650px 10px violet inset;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 100px 15px transparent inset, 0px -10px 10px transparent inset, 0px 250px 20px transparent inset, 0px -20px 10px transparent inset, 0px 400px 30px transparent inset, 3px 650px 10px transparent inset, 0px 100px 15px violet inset, 0px -10px 10px violet inset, 0px 250px 20px plum inset, 0px -20px 10px plum inset, 0px 400px 30px thistle inset, 3px 650px 10px lavender inset;
}
```